# ADMM formulation

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization

I have the following optimization problem
\begin{align}
x^*, y^*&:= \arg\min_{\{x_i\}_i, \{y_j\}_j}~ \sum_{i \in \mathcal{N}_1} f_i(x_i) +  \sum_{j \in \mathcal{N}_2} f_j(y_j)\\ \nonumber \text{s.t. }  &\alpha_{i,j}(k) x_{i}(k) = \alpha_{i,j}(k) y_{j}(k), \forall k, i \in \mathcal{N}_1, m \in \mathcal{N}_2
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{N}_1 \cup \mathcal{N}_2 = \{1,2,\dots,N\}$

In order to get the ADMM formulation, I wrote the lagrangian of the problem as
\begin{align}
\nonumber \mathcal{L}_\rho(\{x_i\}, \{y_j\},\lambda) = &\sum_{i \in \mathcal{N}_1} f_i(x_i) +  \sum_{j \in \mathcal{N}_2} f_j(y_j) + \sum_k \sum_i \sum_j \lambda_{i,j}(k) \alpha_{i,j}(k)(x_{i}(k) - y_{j}(k))\\
& + \frac{\rho}{2} \sum_k \sum_i \sum_j (\alpha_{i,j}(k))^2(x_{i}(k) - y_{j}(k))^2
\end{align}

Then, I tried to write the ADMM formulation as

- For $i \in \mathcal{N}_1$:
  \begin{align}
  \nonumber x_{i}^{t+1}(k) &= \underset{x_{i}}{\arg \min}~ f_i(x_{i}) + \sum_k \sum_j \lambda_{i,j}^{t}(k) \alpha_{i,j}(k) (x_{i}(k)-y_{j}^{t}(k))\\
  & + \frac{\rho}{2} \sum_k \sum_j (\alpha_{i,j}(k))^2 (x_{i}(k)-y_{j}^{t}(k))^2
  \end{align}
- For $j \in \mathcal{N}_2$:
  \begin{align}
  \nonumber y_{j}^{t+1}(k) &= \underset{y_{j}}{\arg \min}~ f_j(y_{j}) + \sum_k \sum_i \lambda_{i,j}^{t}(k) \alpha_{i,j}(k) (x_{i}^{t+1}(k)-y_{j}(k))\\
  & + \frac{\rho}{2} \sum_k \sum_i (\alpha_{i,j}(k))^2 (x_{i}^{t+1}(k)-y_{j}(k))^2
  \end{align}
- Dual variables:
  \begin{align}
  \lambda_{i,j}^{t+1}(k) = \lambda_{i,j}^{t}(k) + \rho \alpha_{i,j}(k) (x_{i}^{t+1}(k) - y_{j}^{t+1}(k))
  \end{align}

I want to check if the formulation I'm making is valid or not. Thanks!

Comment: @Rajat for the $k$ part, it represents the $k^th$ component of the vector, so I'm writing equations per component (not sure if this is the best way to write things).

Comment: aha. write it as ${e_i^k}^{\top}x_i$. I am not very sure about the role of $\alpha_{ij}$. I guess you can remove it from the whole formulation, or else, you need to include it in the dual variable update.